# Wait for one request to finish before starting another one

Tags: javascript, node.js, cheerio

I'm very new to javascript and nodejs. I have to write a web crawler with javascript and then i found cheerio but i have encountered a problem here.

```
function tryLogin(usn, pwd)
{
 var request = require('request');
 var cheerio = require('cheerio');
 var loginLink = 'xyz';
 var loginJar = request.jar();
 var ltValue = '';
 var executionValue = '';
 console.log(1);
 // First request to get session data
 request.get({url: loginLink, jar: loginJar}, function(err, httpResponse, html)
 {
   var dat = cheerio.load(html);
   var arr = dat('input[name="lt"]');
   ltValue = arr.attr('value');
   arr = dat('input[name="execution"]');
   executionValue = arr.attr('value');
   console.log(2);
 });
 console.log(3);
 var loginBody = 'username=' + usn + '&password=' + pwd + '&lt=' + ltValue + '&execuation=' + executionValue
 // Second request to login
 request.post({url: loginLink, jar: loginJar, method: 'post', body: loginBody}, function(err, res, b)
 {

    if (b.indexOf('errors') != -1)
      console.log('Success');
    else console.log('Fail');
 });
}
tryLogin('123', '456');
```

Output:

```
1 3 2
```

It seem to be the first request didn't finish before the second process so "loginBody" didn't complete and i can't login. I'm from C# so i don't understand why it happen here.

Comment: This is a classic asynchronous programming issue in Javascript.  you need to put the second `request.post()` inside the callback from the `request.get()`.  They need to be nested.  Only inside that callback do you have the results you want from the first request and the proper timing to issue the second one.

Comment: I'd suggest reading up on "asynchronous programming in node.js".  You have a lot to learn more than we can explain/teach in an answer here.  Ultimately, this will be simpler to program using the `request-promise` module and using promises to coordinate or sequence your asynchronous requests, but that doesn't change the fundamental understanding of how asynchronous operations work in node.js that you need to have before coding this.